# Facebook AppLinking

Tags: android, facebook, deep-linking

Am new to android. I have added one custom `appLink` schema in my manifest (say `abc://` ). On Clicking of a link from Facebook I need to open my application. I have tested that `appLink` from `adb` using command

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "abc:///settings"
```

and it work perfectly. But where should I add this custom tag. Because when I tried posting in Facebook or any other media, that is not becoming clickable. And I don't know whether I should add any configurations at server side.

If I am trying with `http` / `https` url deep linking, then in Facebook its opening in their own custom browser, its neither redirecting to my application nor to  PlayStore. But same `url` is working fine when click is from default message application

Someone please help.